Expo audio: Can I stop recording automatically?
I've been looking for a solution for Expo-audio and couldn't find solution I wanted, so I made this thread.
What I want
I have a voice recorder functionality with Expo-av and it record, and play audio file which is good. However, I wanted to stop recording automatically when user stop talking.
Explain More about situation
At the Expo Audio page, they have a function Audio.stop() which I have to manually call the method. but the solution is not what the project is looking for.
I tried to set the setTimeout to trigger the stop method, but the project requires actual recording length in ms not programmatically stopped time. so I cannot use the setTimeout. It's relay on user's speech.
I know Web API supports speech end event which satisfy the requirement I have. However, I couldn't get it work on React Native and it makes sense since it's not on browser.
I tried react-native-voice and picovoice; however, it didn't work well with Expo v50+ environment.
My ask
If you successfully integrated auto stop recording functionality with expo v50+, Please share how you did it :)
also if you have work around the solution, please share it as well.
Thank you!

I was looking for the same thing and found this post. I couldn't find anything online either so I asked ChatGPT for a solution and it actually worked for my app. Hopefully this will help you out. Basically there is a property in the recording status called "metering" which allows you to check the level of the recording's audio signal at any point in time. You can use this along with setTimeout to get the functionality you're looking for. I'll copy/paste the output from ChatGPT below (the code from ChatGPT was slightly incorrect as it included a non-existent property called metering.averagePower; I removed that from the snippet below). I also had to modify the constant values after testing.
let silenceTimeout;
let monitoringInterval;
const silenceThreshold = -50; // dB, adjust based on your needs
const silenceDelay = 2000; // 2 seconds

async function monitorRecording() {
  const recordingStatus = await recording.getStatusAsync();

  if (recordingStatus.isRecording) {
    const audioData = await recording.getStatusAsync();
    if (audioData.metering && audioData.metering <= silenceThreshold) {
      if (!silenceTimeout) {
        silenceTimeout = setTimeout(stopRecording, silenceDelay);
      }
    } else {
      clearTimeout(silenceTimeout);
      silenceTimeout = null;
    }
  }
}

function startMonitoring() {
  monitoringInterval = setInterval(monitorRecording, 100); // Check every 100ms
}

function stopMonitoring() {
  clearInterval(monitoringInterval);
}

async function startRecording() {
  try {
    await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
    await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
      allowsRecordingIOS: true,
      playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
    });

    await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY);
    await recording.startAsync();

    startMonitoring();

    console.log('Recording started');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to start recording', error);
  }
}

async function stopRecording() {
  try {
    stopMonitoring();
    await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    const uri = recording.getURI();
    console.log('Recording stopped and stored at', uri);

    // Call your existing stopRecording function or implement further processing
    // stopRecording(); // Your existing function

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to stop recording', error);
  }
}


Let me try! Thank you TSA!
